# jquery .on() with dynamic selector doesn't work

Tags: jquery

I have a little issue with using .on() with a dynamic selector. For instance :

`$("#listPlayerHome").on('click', '.classeJoueurEngland', function(){
     //My work here
}`

...works properly. But if I use a dynamic selector like this :

```
$("#listPlayerHome").on('click', '.classeJoueur'+teamHome, function()
```

Where "teamHome" contains "England", it doesn't work at all.

Comment: Can you post a fiddle?

Comment: It should do, and will do. Are you *sure*, **sure**, ***sure*** it contains `England`? i.e., not `england`, or it's not supposed to be `.classeJoueur-England` (or similar)

Comment: You realize changing the variable value after running the code won't change the selector, right?

Comment: Works fine here http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/4DkKn/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It does work, but it will only happen the once, when the `.on` method is called. If you are expecting it to magically change whenever you change the variable then that will not happen.

If you need it to be dynamic like that then you should rebind whenever you need to change the variable value.

Assuming you only want it to bind the the current value, and forgot previous values, you could do it like this:

```
var oldTeamHome;
function attachHandler(teamHome){
    if(oldTeamHome)
        $("#listPlayerHome").off('click', '.classeJoueur'+oldTeamHome, eventFunction);
    $("#listPlayerHome").on('click', '.classeJoueur'+teamHome, eventFunction);
    oldTeamHome = teamHome;
}

function eventFunction(){
    //...
}
```

That way, wherever you would normally change the `teamHome` value, you would use this instead:

```
//teamHome = "England";
attachHandler("England");
```

---

If by some chance this is not what you want, and it does infact NOT work. Then it is because you are doing something wrong else. In this case you need to provide a full set of code that can replicate the issue.

Comment: Perfect! Thanks! I needed to attach a handler, like in your example.

Answer (score 0):

It should work, but you mention that teamHome *contains* England -- maybe it has a space beforehand?  So perhaps try:

```
$("#listPlayerHome").on('click', '.classeJoueur' + teamHome.trim(), function()
```

Answer (score 0):

This is not an exact solution to your approach, but another way to look at the problem.

You could try using an [Attribute Starts with Selector](https://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector/). This will attach the event binding to any children element with classes that begin with "classeJoueur".

```
$('#listPlayerHome').children('*[class^="classeJoueur"]').on('click', function () { });
```